# WPF ComboBox DisplayMemberPath when no ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a `ComboBox`, some hardcoded `ComboBoxItems` and I am trying to show whatever the `Content` of the item contains.

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0"
          SelectedValuePath="Tag"
          DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Content}">

     <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Item2" Tag="sometag1" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Item3" Tag="sometag2" />
     <ComboBoxItem Content="Item4" Tag="sometag3" />
</ComboBox>
```

I am struggling with how to set the `DisplayMemberPath`. Currently, I set it as `{Binding Content}`. If I insert the above code into a blank WPF project, the `Content` is shown correctly like below.

[image: Combobox]

Then I copy exactly the same code in another bigger project, select the first item and nothing is shown:

[image: Combobox inserted into bigger project]

I don't understand how this is possible. The `Combobox` code should be totally independent of the other part of the project. There is only theme applied and the visual look is different.

Is there something in `DisplayMemberPath` done wrongly or what can explain this?

Comment: have you tried removing SelectedValuePath="Tag"
          DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Content}" and then checking?

Comment: `DisplayMemberPath="Content"` ? Also check output window to see if there any binding error message related to this code...

Comment: @user2143213 why do you need `DisplayMemberPath`? It will display `Content` anyway.

Comment: Removing DisplayMemberPath doesn't help. Nor does removing SelectedValuePath. I have also identified this problem relates to the applied theme somehow. If theme not applied, everything works.

Comment: I hope its not coz of some style on this black combo ?

Answer (score 1):

I find that if I set `DisplayMemberPath` to the empty string, it causes the `Content` to be displayed in the collapsed combo box, even when a theme is applied to the application.  Hope this helps.

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0"
      SelectedValuePath="Tag"
      DisplayMemberPath="">
```